# Benchmarking, sequential x parallel program. Sublinear speedup?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, benchmarking

Update2. Solved! This is memory issue. Some benching about it here:
http://dontpad.com/bench_mem

Update. My goal is to achieve best throughput. All my results are here.

Sequential Results:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjKHxPB2qgJXdE8yQVNHRkRiQ2VzeElIRWwxMWtRcVE&usp=sharing

Parallel Results*:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjKHxPB2qgJXdEhTb2plT09PNEs3ajBvWUlVaWt0ZUE&usp=sharing

multsoma_par1_vN, N determines how data is acessed by each thread.
N: 1 - NTHREADS displacement, 2 - L1 displacement, 3 - L2 displacement, 4 - TAM/NTHREADS

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why my parallel code runs just slighty faster than sequential code.

What I basically do is to loop through a big array (10^8 elements) of a type (int/float/double) and apply the computation: A = A * CONSTANT + B. Where A and B are arrays of same size.

Sequential code only do a single function call.
Parallel version create pthreads and uses the same function as starting function.

I am using gettimeofday(), RDTSC() and more recently getrusage() to measure timings. My main results are expressed by Clocks per Element (CPE).

My processor is an i5-3570K. 4 Cores, no hyper-threading.

The problem is that I can get up to 2.00 CPE under sequential code and when going parallel my best performance was 1.84 CPE. I know that I get an overhead by creating pthreads and calling more timing routines, but I don't think this is the reason for not getting better timings.
I did measured each thread CPE and executed the program with 1, 2, 3 and 4 threads. When creating only one thread, I get the expected result CPE around 2.00 (+ some overhead expressed in miliseconds but overall CPE is not affected at all). 
When running with 2 threads or more the main CPE decreases, but each thread CPE increases.
2 threads I get main CPE around 1.9 and each thread to 3.8 ( Why this is not 2.0 ?! )
The same happens to 3 and 4 threads.
4 threads I get main CPE around 1.85 (my best timing) and each thread with 7.0~7.5 CPE.

Using many threads more than avaiable cores(4) I still getting CPE under 2.0 but not better than 1.85 (most times higher due to overhead).

I suspect that maybe context switching could be the limiting factor here. When running with 2 threads I can count 5 to 10 involuntary contexts switch from each thread...
But I am not so sure about this. Are those seemly few context switches enough to almost double my CPE ? I was expecting to atleast get around 1.00 CPE using all my CPU Cores.

I went further on this and analyzed the assembly code for this function. They are identical, except for some extra shifts and adds (4 instructions) at the very beginning of the function and they are out of loops.

In case you want to see some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cpuid.h>

typedef union{
   unsigned long long int64;
   struct {unsigned int lo, hi;} int32;
} tsc_counter;

#define RDTSC(cpu_c)                 \
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" :    \
  "=a" ((cpu_c).int32.lo),           \
  "=d" ((cpu_c).int32.hi) )

#define CNST 5
#define NTHREADS 4
#define L1_SIZE 8096
#define L2_SIZE 72512

typedef int data_t;

data_t * A;
data_t * B;

int tam;
double avg_thread_CPE;
tsc_counter thread_t0[NTHREADS], thread_t1[NTHREADS];
struct timeval thread_sec0[NTHREADS], thread_sec1[NTHREADS];

void fillA_B(int tam){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<tam;i++){
        A[i]=2; B[i]=2;
    }
    return;
}

void* multsoma_par4_v4(void *arg){
    int w;
    int i,j;
    int *id = (int *) arg;
    int limit = tam-14;
    int size = tam/NTHREADS;
    int tam2 = ((*id+1)*size);
    int limit2 = tam2-14;

    gettimeofday(&thread_sec0[*id],NULL);
    RDTSC(thread_t0[*id]);

    //Mult e Soma
    for (i=(*id)*size;i<limit2 && i<limit;i+=15){
          A[i] = A[i] * CNST + B[i];
          A[i+1] = A[i+1] * CNST + B[i+1];
          A[i+2] = A[i+2] * CNST + B[i+2];
          A[i+3] = A[i+3] * CNST + B[i+3];
        A[i+4] = A[i+4] * CNST + B[i+4];
        A[i+5] = A[i+5] * CNST + B[i+5];
        A[i+6] = A[i+6] * CNST + B[i+6];
        A[i+7] = A[i+7] * CNST + B[i+7];
        A[i+8] = A[i+8] * CNST + B[i+8];
        A[i+9] = A[i+9] * CNST + B[i+9];
        A[i+10] = A[i+10] * CNST + B[i+10];
        A[i+11] = A[i+11] * CNST + B[i+11];
        A[i+12] = A[i+12] * CNST + B[i+12];
        A[i+13] = A[i+13] * CNST + B[i+13];
        A[i+14] = A[i+14] * CNST + B[i+14];
    }

    for (; i<tam2 && i<tam; i++)
        A[i] = A[i] * CNST + B[i];

    RDTSC(thread_t1[*id]);
    gettimeofday(&thread_sec1[*id],NULL);

    double CPE, elapsed_time;

    CPE = ((double)(thread_t1[*id].int64-thread_t0[*id].int64))/((double)(size)); 

    elapsed_time = (double)(thread_sec1[*id].tv_sec-thread_sec0[*id].tv_sec)*1000;
    elapsed_time+= (double)(thread_sec1[*id].tv_usec - thread_sec0[*id].tv_usec)/1000;  
    //printf("Thread %d workset - %d\n",*id,size);
    //printf("CPE Thread %d - %lf\n",*id, CPE);    
    //printf("Time Thread %d - %lf\n",*id, elapsed_time/1000);
    avg_thread_CPE+=CPE;


    free(arg);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void imprime(int tam){
    int i;
    int ans = 12;
    for (i=0;i<tam;i++){
        //printf("%d ",A[i]);
        //checking...
        if (A[i]!=ans) printf("WA!!\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    tsc_counter t0,t1;
    struct timeval sec0,sec1;
    pthread_t thread[NTHREADS];

    double CPE;
    double elapsed_time;      

    int i;
    int* id;

    tam = atoi(argv[1]);  

    A = (data_t*) malloc (tam*sizeof(data_t));
    B = (data_t*) malloc (tam*sizeof(data_t));

    fillA_B(tam);
    avg_thread_CPE = 0;

    //Start Computing... 
     gettimeofday(&sec0,NULL);
     RDTSC(t0);                                  //Time Stamp 0

    for (i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++){     
        id = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));   
        *id = i;
        if (pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, multsoma_par4_v4, (void*)id)) {
             printf("--ERRO: pthread_create()\n"); exit(-1);
          }

    } 

    for (i=0; i<NTHREADS; i++) {
         if (pthread_join(thread[i], NULL)) {
              printf("--ERRO: pthread_join() \n"); exit(-1); 
         } 
    }


     RDTSC(t1);                                  //Time Stamp 1
     gettimeofday(&sec1,NULL);
    //End Computing...

    imprime(tam);

    CPE = ((double)(t1.int64-t0.int64))/((double)(tam));        //diferenca entre Time_Stamps/repeticoes

     elapsed_time = (double)(sec1.tv_sec-sec0.tv_sec)*1000;
     elapsed_time+= (double)(sec1.tv_usec - sec0.tv_usec)/1000;

     printf("Main CPE: %lf\n",CPE);
     printf("Avg Thread CPE: %lf\n",avg_thread_CPE/NTHREADS);
     printf("Time: %lf\n",elapsed_time/1000);
     free(A); free(B);

    return 0;   
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: int *id = (int *) arg; - this looks suspicious. Typically, a thread index is passed by value, not by pointer. How do you create your threads?

Comment: @Alexey Kukanov This is not a issue, it works. This function is the one used by pthread_create call, and so I must pass the argument as void *.

Comment: I suspect an error that I have seen a few times: threads are created in a loop, and the address of the loop index is passed as the parameter to all threads. It leads to multiple data races and undefined behavior. If you are sure this is not an issue, and each thread receives an address of a distinct variable, great.

Comment: `int size = tam/NTHREADS;` - if `tam` is your total number of elements, then that division might leave a rest.

Comment: You are doing a lot of memory operations, and basically no computing. I guess, that the memory bandwidth is the limiting factor in this case. Maybe [perf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_(Linux)) can give you more insights.

Comment: @Alexey Kukanov I edited and pasted all the code. I am using the loop index as the thread index... But I don't think this is the issue because when I run the "imprime" routine it checks for correctness and it is correct.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I am aware of that. I am using even number of threads and 100000000 elements, it works.

Comment: @nosid That is a good guess. But I am acessing different data by each thread, no conflicts... I used perf before, I can try using it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the full code, I rather agree with the guess of @nosid in comments: since the ratio of compute operations to memory loads is low, and the data (about 800M if I am not mistaken) don't fit in cache, the memory bandwidth is likely the limiting factor. The link to the main memory is shared to all cores in a processor, so when its bandwidth is saturated, all memory operations start stalling and take longer time; thus CPE increases.

Also, the following place in your code is a data race:

```
avg_thread_CPE+=CPE;
```

as you sum up CPE values calculated on different threads to a single global variable without any synchronization.

---

Below I left the part of my initial answer, including the "first statement" referred in the comments. I still find it correct, for the definition of CPE as the number of clocks taken by the operations over a single element.

> You should not expect the clocks per element (CPE) metric to decrease
>   due to use of multiple threads. By definition, it's how fast a
>   *single* data item is processed, in average. Threading helps to process all data faster (by simultaneous processing on different
>   cores), so the elapsed wallclock time, i.e. the time to execute the
>   whole program, should be expected to decrease.

Comment: I don't agree with your first statement.
Each thread CPE shouldn't decrease either. 
And you are right, the avg_thread_CPE variable is not synchronized at any moment (I have to fix this). But don't think its the problem, as I get this value to be the sum of all threads CPE and the avg CPE is reliable. This average is = avg_thread_CPE/NTHREADS.
My main CPE is calculated with another isolated call to RDTS wrapping all pthread creation.
I get 3.8 CPE only by ONE RDTSC call of ONE thread. Summing them up is 7.6 (2 threads) with avg 3.8 (divide by 2)... Code edited in full length, thanks for help.

Comment: What you call "main CPE" is not really an (average) number of clocks per processing an element. Rather, it's a reciprocal to the throughput - the number of elements processed per a time unit. This value, indeed, may be expected to decrease as the number of threads is growing. Now I understand what you meant.

Comment: Yeah, the minimum throughput should be 2 CPE. But when using 2 threads in parallel, it should be 2 CPE each and overall 1 CPE for main.
I am very suspicious that there might be something to do with the memory. Or maybe some optimization done by compiler with only one thread is not done to 2 or more. I am compiling under -O2.
I will run perf and track cache memory misses. Updated thread with all my benchmarking results.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I finally used perf to check the memory. I am almost sure it is indeed memory the limiting factor. Don't know if it is the bandwith or cache misses or both.
There is more cache-misses when using more threads. 2 threads add about 10% of cache-misses and 4 threads 20%. It is about 1x10^6 or 2x10^6 more misses. This costs, don't know if enough to be the limiting factor, but then we will have many threads requesting memory to one controller... So yeah, this must be it! Thanks!